# Does mezzanine allow custom navigation items to be displayed according to a custom permission?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, mezzanine, django-permissions

I have a system that uses mezzanine custom navigation items to display some navigation items. However, I want the navigation items to only be displayed if a user have a specific set of permissions which are custom and not really Model based. Does mezzanine support this? Sample code

```
ADMIN_MENU_ORDER = (
    ('Customer service'),
        (
            ('Customer X OverX', 'summary_e'),
```

`summary_e` is a `URL`.
How can I ensure `Customer service` is only displayed if a user has certain permission?